# Best approach docker

Tags: node.js, heroku, microservices

I have an application with the following architecture microservices to implement. My question is how to use the docker:

I must:
[image]

I see three scenarios and have no doubt that the most efficient:

[image]

My service should be easy to scale because it is an application with significant amounts of requests, and your stay will be made at heroku, I wonder which of the three scenario will be more effective, I'm new to microservices and I have no idea what best approach.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is really down to how or how intensive your services are used. The beauty of microservices architecture is the services are completely independent to each other so you have the freedom to configure your infrastructure the way you want to maximise throughput. The use of docker seems a little bit irrelevant to your question.